# How to check content of jquery element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to learn some jquery. In my html page I have something like this:

```
<li>
    <ul>
       <p>This ul has text</p>
    </ul>
</li>

<li>
    <ul></ul>
</li>
```

I'm trying to do something if the tag 'ul' doesn't have any content

```
var $ul = $li.find(' > ul')
if( $ul.text() == null || $ul.text == ""){
    alert("Empty ul");
}else{ 
    alert("Not empty ul");
}
```

I get the alert with "not empty ul" everytime, so the if-statement is never true.

How can I check correctly if there is nothing inside the 'ul' tags?

Comment: Your markup is missing `</p>`, or is that just from when you entered the question?

Comment: Just as a heads up, the only valid direct descendent elements of unordered lists elements is a list item. You can nest a paragraph element inside of the list item, but it's invalid to nest it directly inside the unordered list as shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [:empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) selector

```
var $ul = $li.find(' > ul')
if( $ul.is(':empty')){
    alert("Empty ul");
}else{ 
    alert("Not empty ul");
}
```

Comment: Is there a difference between using `children('ul')` and `find('>ul')`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [:empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/)

```
$('ul:empty').each(
```

If you want to check ul that only have spaces between them then you can use filter and trim to get `ul`

```
$('ul').filter(function(){
   rturn $.trim($(this).text()) == "";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In the if statement, `$ul.text` should have parenthesis and be `$ul.text()`:

```
if( $ul.text() == null || $ul.text() == ""){
```

You might also want to trim it, if there could be whitespace:

```
if( $ul.text() == null || $.trim($ul.text()) == ""){
```

Or use the `:empty` selector in combination with `.is()`:

```
if($ul.is(':empty')){
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('ul:empty').each(function(){ 
   //-- Do your stuff
});
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/kU8fC/1/)